# docker Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm having issues building my Dockerfile (on OS X), getting the above error for multiple libraries. I've tried adding google dns servers and the below sources.list workaround but nothing that I've found online solves my issue.

: sources.list "fix"

```
  RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -sc) main universe Trusty-updates" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

: portion of dockerfile

```
  FROM ubuntu:14.10
  RUN echo exit 101 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

  RUN apt-get install -y  --fix-missing software-properties-common 

  RUN apt-get update
```

:output of build

```
  Step 15 : RUN apt-get install -y  --fix-missing software-properties-common
   ---> Running in 6067adba2748
  Reading package lists...
  Building dependency tree...
  Reading state information...
  The following extra packages will be installed:
    ca-certificates gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal
     libcurl3-gnutls libdbus-glib-1-2 libgcrypt20 libgirepository-1.0-1
    libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal
    libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
    libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal
    libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1
    libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libwind0-heimdal libxml2
    openssl python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi python3-pycurl
    python3-software-properties sgml-base shared-mime-info unattended-upgrades
    xdg-user-dirs xml-core xz-utils
  Suggested packages:
    isoquery rng-tools krb5-doc krb5-user libsasl2-modules-otp
    libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-sql libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
    libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc
    python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-doc
    python3-pycurl-dbg sgml-base-doc bsd-mailx mail-transport-agent debhelper
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
   ca-certificates gir1.2-glib-2.0 iso-codes krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal
   libcurl3-gnutls libdbus-glib-1-2 libgcrypt20 libgirepository-1.0-1
    libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal
   libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal
   libhx509-5-heimdal libidn11 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-26-heimdal
   libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1
   libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libwind0-heimdal libxml2
   openssl python-apt-common python3-apt python3-dbus python3-gi python3-pycurl
   python3-software-properties sgml-base shared-mime-info
   software-properties-common unattended-upgrades xdg-user-dirs xml-core
   xz-utils
   0 upgraded, 45 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 8227 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 45.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main libroken18-heimdal amd64 1.6~rc2+dfsg-8
    Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]
    Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 1.6~rc2+dfsg-8
    Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]
   Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main libkrb5support0 amd64 1.12.1+dfsg-10
   Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]

   ...

   Unable to correct missing packages. 
    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libroken18- heimdal_1.6~rc2+dfsg-8_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]

    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/heimdal/libasn1-8- heimdal_1.6~rc2+dfsg-8_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]

    Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 209.6.3.210 80]

    ...


    E: Aborting install.
       2014/12/12 10:24:32 The command [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y  --fix-missing software-   properties-common] returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you running `apt-get update` after `apt-get install`? I think the problem you have is that your repository cache has a dead server and you can not connect to it. This Dockerfile is working right now:

```
  FROM ubuntu:14.10
  RUN echo exit 101 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d && chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

  RUN apt-get update

  RUN apt-get install -y  --fix-missing software-properties-common
```

Comment: @jcpnrad ha, just typo from adding/removing/re-arranging the script...in hopes something works lol. Thanks for the info